# Separate site for website and web application - implications for SEO?

Tags: seo, web-applications, architecture

I have a web application - primarily reserved for members but with some open access for trialling, and I have a website that is the main public face for the web application. The two are on two different websites.

The main function of the website is to describe what you can do on the web application. If you want to try the app, the website sends you over to the web application.

Are there any implications for SEO from this setup?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easy answer is yes.

if you have 2 domain names for the same thing the organic results might get "divided" between both sites. Like if they were competing for attention.

As a rule of thumb it's always easier to market a single domain name. The problem with two is that organic links will be divided. some people will link to your marketing site, others to the app site.

If you REALLY need to have 2 domains for some setup reason try subdomains instead.   like www.app.com for the marketing and run.app.com for the actual app.  The problem will continue but somewhat good algorithms (like google) will come to terms with it.